# How do I round trip an entitized carriage return with XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Suppose I have this XML document:

```
<x xml:space='preserve'>&#xd;
</x>
```

with this sequence of bytes as the content of the `<x/>`:

```
38 35 120 100 59 13 10
```

My understanding from the W3C spec is that the sequence `13 10` [will be replaced before parsing](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-white-space). To get the sequence `13 10` to show up in my parsed tree, I have to include the character entity `&xd;` as [clarified in a note in the W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-common-syn) (I recognize these are from XML-1.1 instead of XML-1.0, but they clarify confusing things in XML-1.0 without describing a different behavior).

> As explained in [2.11 End-of-Line Handling](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-line-ends), all #xD characters literally present in an XML document are either removed or replaced by #xA characters before any other processing is done. The only way to get a #xD character to match this production is to use a character reference in an entity value literal.

With [`XDocument.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this all seems to work correctly. The text content for the above XML is `13 10` (rather than `13 13 10`), suggesting that the character entity is preserved and the literal `13 10` is replaced with `10` prior to parsing.

However, I can’t figure out how to get `XDocument.ToString()` to entitize newlines when serializing. I.e., I’d expect `(XDocument xd) => XDocument.Parse($"{xd}")` to be a lossless function. But if I pass in an `XDocument` instance with `13 10` as text content, that function outputs an `XDocument` instance with `10` as text content. See this demonstration:

```
var x = XDocument.Parse("<x xml:space='preserve'>&#xd;\r\n</x>");
present("content", x.Root.Value); // 13 10, expected
present("formatted", $"{x}"); // inside <x/>: 13 10, unexpected
x = XDocument.Parse($"{x}");
present("round tripped", x.Root.Value); // 10, unexpected

// Note that when formatting the version with just 10 in the value,
// we get Environment.NewLine in the formatted XML. So there is no
// way to differentiate between 10 and 13 10 with XDocument because
// it normalizes when serializing.
present("round tripped formatted", $"{x}"); // inside <x/>: 13 10, expected

void present(string label, string thing)
{
    Console.WriteLine(label);
    Console.WriteLine(thing);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(thing)));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You can see that when `XDocument` is serialized, it fails to entitize the carriage return as either `&#xd;` or `&#10;`. The result is that it loses information. How can I safely encode an `XDocument` so that I do not lose anything, particularly carriage returns, that were in the original document I loaded?

Comment: As per site etiquette, may downvoters please comment with rationale? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To round-trip `XDocument`, **do not use the [recommended/easy serialization methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/preserving-white-space-while-serializing) such as [`XDocument.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) because this is lossy**. Note also that, **even if you do something like `xd.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)`, any carriage returns in the parsed tree will be lost**.

Instead, use a properly-configured `XmlWriter` with [`XDocument.WriteTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.writeto?view=netframework-4.7.2). If using an `XmlWriter`, the `XmlWriter` will be able to see that the document contained literal carriage returns and encode them correctly. To instruct it to do so, set [`XmlWritterSettings.NewLineHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinehandling?view=netframework-4.7.2) to [`NewLineHandling.Entitize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.newlinehandling?view=netframework-4.7.2). You’ll probably want to write an extension method to make this easier to reuse.

The demo altered to use this approach is below:

```
var x = XDocument.Parse("<x xml:space='preserve'>&#xd;\r\n</x>");
present("content", x.Root.Value); // 13 10, expected
present("formatted", toString(x)); // inside <x/>: 38 35 120 68 59 10 ("&#xD;\n"), acceptable
x = XDocument.Parse(toString(x));
present("round tripped", x.Root.Value); // 13 10, expected

string toString(XDocument xd)
{
    using var sw = new StringWriter();
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize,
    }))
    {
        xd.WriteTo(writer);
    }
    return sw.ToString();
}

void present(string label, string thing)
{
    Console.WriteLine(label);
    Console.WriteLine(thing);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(thing)));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```